# How can i built this tab menu on sublime text 2?

Tags: tabs, sublimetext2

[image]

Like this, how do I set up?

ps:  **my sublime text is version 2**

Comment: That looks like Sublime Text 3 on Windows.

Comment: yes, this is ST3. Does ST2 has this funtion? and how to set up?

Answer (score 1):

This is a one sneaky setting I wasted time to find out how to turn off:

```
// Allows tabs to scroll left and right, instead of simply shrinking
"enable_tab_scrolling": true,
```

See if it's available in ST2. Interesting part is that it's disabled on OS X by default, but enabled on Linux and Windows.

Comment: You may answer your own question and accept your answer for the sake of wiki and welcome to SO!